# Scanning Spring Data repositories by Spring Config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

I'm trying to use spring data and spring config together in a small standalone application.

```
...
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {        
    ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
    ... 
  }
```

**1.** My question is how can I discover the spring data repositories without using

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="foo.repositories" />
```

by spring config ?

**2.** If not, can I use 'ClassPathXmlApplicationContext' and 'AnnotationConfigApplicationContext' together somehow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer is now out of date.**

Currently there's no equivalent for `<jpa:repositories … />` yet. Feel free tor track the according [JIRA ticket](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATACMNS-47). The feature will be a major one for the upcoming GA releases of the JPA module (1.1) as well as MongoDB (1.1).

Answer (score 73):

You can now use the annotation `@EnableJpaRepositories("some.root.package")` .

For example:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableJpaRepositories("some.root.package")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "maybe.another.root.package" })
public class SystemConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

([Spring Data's announcement](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/10/15/spring-data-release-train-arrived/#whats-in-this-release))

Comment: This is now the correct answer. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

For completeness' sake and to address your second question: Yes, you can combine Java and XML configurations. This way you don't have to wait for the next Spring Data JPA release.

Just annotate your configuration class with [ImportResource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportResource.html), like this:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource("classpath:jpa-config.xml")
public class AppConfig {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have a look at context:component-scan

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.myProject"/>
```

It autodetects components annotated with @Repository/@Service/@Component . Check [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-classpath-scanning) for this .

Comment: Using @Repository annotation on 'public interface Repository<T, ID extends Serializable>' interfaces belongs to Spring Data context. Anyway thanks for your help and time.