# Configure spring-data-mongodb repositories with Spring 3.1's Java configuration

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

```
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.acme.*.repositories" />
```

Is there a way to do this with new Java based `@Configuration` support?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610428/scaning-spring-data-repositories-by-spring-config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use: `@EnableMongoRepositories` as of Spring Data JPA 2.1

https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATACMNS-47

This works in a similar way to `@ComponentScan`