# What is equivalent for `<jpa:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />` in Java Config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-java-config

It is said, that to use Spring Data repositories, I should mention it's package with

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />
```

in Spring XML config. But I don't have one since I am using Java config. How to set the same with Java config?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610428/scanning-spring-data-repositories-by-spring-config

Comment: Nothing to do with the JPA API. This is Spring Data JPA

Comment: @NeilStockton where did I said it is just `JPA`?

Comment: I referred to JPA API, __not__ Spring Data JPA API. They are totally different APIs, and you use Spring Data JPA. Consequently the question has zero relevance for JPA API.